# spring use multiple data sources

Tags: spring, c3p0

I have one requirement where need to put multiple data sources using spring-hibernate. I am using C3P0 connection pool
Couple of questions:
1. Should I have common application pool to all data sources? How is it better?
2. If yes, then how can it be implemented.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation

Comment: I am using spring for transaction management, and used class extending AbstractRoutingDataSource for multiple datasource. Also used C3p0 for connection pooling, is there any way we can use same C3P0 connection pool as shared one

Comment: Is there any way we can use one application pool using C3P0